# Align horizontally element of table in html page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

I need my angular material and css table to be able to take the full width of my div, but it doesn't work.
Also in my header, I want the image to be in the background.
This is the stackblitz link of my work: https://stackblitz.com/github/lnquaidorsay/bibliofront  or https://nbwiyjwnw.github.stackblitz.io/product

```
<div class="container">
    <div fxFlex="60">
        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                <!-- Position Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Weight Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Symbol Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>

            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The products table seems to already be 100% wide. I guess you finally fixed it.

About the header background, remove the image from within the `mat-toolbar-row` element and add this css code to `mat-toolbar`:

```
mat-toolbar {
  background-image: url('<path/to/image>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```